# Caching downloads for Vagrant

Tags: vagrant, vagrant-provision

I am looking for the way to cache installation files for Vagrant environment assuming that boxes is properly populated from `vagrant box add`. The idea is to be able to test/develop box provisioning in offline environment later after initial download steps or to save time on downloading same artifacts for identical node copies (for example if I want to run 10 identical slaves).

My initial thought is to download necessary files to Vagrant project to shared folder and use those files during provisioning (so I don't need to do repetitive `curl`/`wget` for each boxes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote:

```
$share = "share"

Dir.mkdir($share) unless Dir.exist?($share)

# https://pkg.jenkins.io/debian/
$jenkins_deb_url = "https://pkg.jenkins.io/debian/binary/jenkins_2.86_all.deb"
$jenkins_deb_file = $share+"/jenkins.deb"

if ! File.exist?($jenkins_deb_file)
  require 'open-uri'
  download = open($jenkins_deb_url)
  IO.copy_stream(download, $jenkins_deb_file)
end
```

It isn't perfect. I can't automate downloading of `apt-get install` dependencies reliably (that is necessary to satisfy dependencies for Jenkins) to make it completely offline.